# add custom options programmatically while adding product from admin

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to add custom options to each product while adding product in magento 1.9.

I found many article to do that but it is very confusing where to put the code.

I need step by step and code and file changes.

Answer (score 0):

**Custom options:**

Custom options are easy to create since you do not require to maintain separate products as the individual variants. But this practice will only work for you if you have a small catalog or a Make to Order model. In case you have huge line up of products custom options would not be suitable as you will not be able to keep track of the inventory of the custom option variants.

**Create custom options:**

From the Admin panel, select Catalog > Manage Products.
In the list, click to open the product record.
In the Product Information panel on the left, select Custom Options.
In the upper-right corner, click the Add New Option button. Then, complete the following fields:
**For Configurable Product>>>**

A Configurable product in Magento is a combination of simple products. Configurable Products are introduced to provide options to the eCommerce customers to choose and build their product. Since each variant is considered as a simple product in this practice, you can maintain the inventory separately for each variant.

**Create custom options for Configurable products:**

Considering the above scenario first you will have to create two Attributes.
i. From the Admin panel, select Catalog > Attributes> Manage Attributes

ii. In the Attribute record list page click on the “Add New Attribute button”

iii.  Provide the Attribute Code (name) as Color, select the Scope as “Global”, Input type as “Dropdown”, Apply to as “Selected Product Types” and select option Simple Product, Select “yes” for Creating Configurable product.

iv.   In the Product Information panel on the left, select Manage Label